# Wrap flex items while fixing the height of flex container to the tallest child

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 4 div’s in a flex-container and would like to decrease the space 
between the two div’s indicated in the attached image (Current). 
I already gave the flex-container the “wrap”-prop. How can I handle that?

**Current**

[image: current_state]

**Desired**

[image: desired_state]

html

```
<div className="flex-container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: space-around;

    div {
        width: 30%;
        min-width: 300px;
    }
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the linked answer I solved my issue by wrapping the two divs in the center in an overarching div.